# Is there a way to convert list of unequal length to dataframe in R

Tags: r

I see the below code is working while converting lists to dataframe

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, list(list(symbol = "ABC", name = "ABCVFD"), list(symbol = "XYZ", name = "Ni"), list(symbol = "GFD", name = NULL)))

Error in (function (..., deparse.level = 1, make.row.names = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors(),  : 
invalid list argument: all variables should have the same length
```

Expected output

```
      symbol   name
1     ABC      ABCVFD
2     XYZ      Ni
3     GFD      NULL
```

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows(YOUR_LIST)` seems to work here.

Comment: tried but got error ````dplyr::bind_rows(list(list(symbol = "ABC", name = "ABCVFD"), list(symbol = "XYZ", name = "Ni"), list(symbol = "GFD", name = NULL)))
Error in `vec_rbind()`:
! `proxy` of type `character` incompatible with `value` proxy of type `NULL`.
i In file slice-assign.c at line 156.
i This is an internal error in the rlang package, please report it to the package authors.
Backtrace:
    x
 1. +-dplyr::bind_rows(...)
 2. | \-vctrs::vec_rbind(!!!dots, .names_to = .id)
 3. \-rlang:::stop_internal_c_lib(...)
 4.   \-rlang::abort(message, call = call, .internal = TRUE)````

Comment: This `dplyr::bind_rows(list(list(symbol = "ABC", name = "ABCVFD"), list(symbol = "XYZ", name = "Ni"), list(symbol = "GFD", name = NULL)))` works for me without error.

Comment: Also, the output will be `NA` for the missing variable, not `NULL`

Comment: I suspect the error you see will be resolved if you update your `dplyr` and `rlang` versions. I see this bug mentioned in an error report from Sept 2022: https://github.com/r-quantities/units/issues/324#issuecomment-1249404831

Comment: Also, if you don't want to update `dplyr` and `rlang` and want to keep `NULL`, you can just do `data.frame(do.call(rbind, thelist))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) rbindlist** You probably want an NA in the last position because otherwise that column will necessarily be a list column.  To do that define a function which replaces NULL with NA and then run `rbindlist`  Alternately just run `rbindlist(L)` without `null2na` if you don't mind a warning message.  `L` is defined in the Note at the end based on the question.

```
null2na <- function(x) {
  if (is.list(x)) lapply(x, null2na)
  else if (is.null(x)) NA
  else x
}

library(data.table)

L |> null2na() |> rbindlist()

##    symbol   name
## 1:    ABC ABCVFD
## 2:    XYZ     Ni
## 3:    GFD   <NA>
```

**2) Base R** Alternately the code in the question works if you run `null2na` from (1) first:

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, null2na(L))

##   symbol   name
## 1    ABC ABCVFD
## 2    XYZ     Ni
## 3    GFD   <NA>
```

**3) recombinator** A third possibility is `recombinator` in the package of the same name.

```
library("recombinator")

recombinator(L)

##   symbol   name
## 1    ABC ABCVFD
## 2    XYZ     Ni
## 3    GFD   <NA>
```

**4) rrapply** `rrapply` in the package of the same name can also be used if we run `null2na` first.

```
library(rrapply)

rrapply(null2na(L), how = "bind")

##   symbol   name
## 1    ABC ABCVFD
## 2    XYZ     Ni
## 3    GFD   <NA>
```

Actually `rrapply` can be used to replace `null2na` so that a double application of rrapply works.  The first application replaces `null2na` and the second converts it to a data.frame.

```
L |>
  rrapply(classes = "NULL", f = \(x) NA, how = "replace") |> 
  rrapply(how = "bind")

##   symbol   name
## 1    ABC ABCVFD
## 2    XYZ     Ni
## 3    GFD   <NA>
```

**5) tibblify** `tibblify` in the package of the same name can do this.

```
library(tibblify)

tibblify(L)

## # A tibble: 3 × 2
##   symbol name  
##   <chr>  <chr> 
## 1 ABC    ABCVFD
## 2 XYZ    Ni    
## 3 GFD    <NA>
```

### Note

```
L <- list(list(symbol = "ABC", name = "ABCVFD"), 
  list(symbol = "XYZ", name = "Ni"), list(symbol = "GFD", name = NULL))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dplyr::bind_rows(L)  # I'm using dplyr 1.1.3
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  symbol name  
  <chr>  <chr> 
1 ABC    ABCVFD
2 XYZ    Ni    
3 GFD    NA
```

where

```
L <- list(list(symbol = "ABC", name = "ABCVFD"), 
          list(symbol = "XYZ", name = "Ni"),
          list(symbol = "GFD", name = NULL))
```